# how to get flutter textfield value to datepicker

Tags: flutter, dart

**When I enter date in text field in "MM/dd/yyyy" than how to assign same value to date picker**

```
          Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: birthDateInputController,
                    validator: Utils.birthDateValidator,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
                      birthDateInput,
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_today_rounded,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                      DateTime pickedDate = await showDate();
                      if (pickedDate != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          intl.DateFormat formatter =
                              intl.DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
                          String formatted = formatter.format(pickedDate);
                          birthDateInputController.text = formatted;
                          birthDate = pickedDate;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),

Future<DateTime> showDate() async {
return await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(1920),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
);
```

}

- and When I select value to date picker than assign to the text field
- but when I enter date in text field than can't assign to the date picker

Comment: add onChanged listener to TextField Controller (birthDateInputController) then change the date in that method and pass the changed date to showDate() method !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Assign to DatePicker. you need to add couple of things in `Future<DateTime> showDate(String dateTime)`

```
    Future<DateTime> showDate(String dateTime) async {
    DateTime _dateTime;
    if (dateTime.isNotEmpty) {
      _dateTime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(dateTime);
    } else {
      _dateTime = DateTime.now();
    }
    return await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _dateTime,
      firstDate: DateTime(1920),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
  }
```

Pass your text in this showDate() Method in onPressed

```
 onPressed: () async {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                  DateTime pickedDate = await showDate(birthDateInputController.text);
                  if (pickedDate != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      intl.DateFormat formatter =
                          intl.DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
                      String formatted = formatter.format(pickedDate);
                      birthDateInputController.text = formatted;
                      birthDate = pickedDate;
                    });
                  }
                },
```

And in **TextFormField** you only have to pass the **number** and **forward slash** for that

```
 TextFormField(
                controller: birthDateInputController,
                validator: Utils.birthDateValidator,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime, // use this parameter
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9/]')), // for numbers only
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10), //set the number limit including slash
                  birthDateInput,
                ],
              ),
```

Make a validation which the date is correct format when typing

Answer (score 0):

In your showDate() function you used `initialDate: DateTime.now()` which take the todays date as initial date

So now you should set the initialDate as manually

Try to implement showDate() method like

```
Future<DateTime> showDate(int year, int month, int day, int hr, int min, int sec) async {
    return await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(year, month, day, hr, min, sec),
      firstDate: DateTime(1920),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. you could give me an upvote too.